# AngularJS - Set title attribute

Tags: angularjs

I want to set an title attribute if a certain a condition is true. If content is avaiblabe I want to set a class and the alt text. How can I set the title text?

HTML

```
<li ng-class="{true: 'my_class', false: ''}[content]"  title="this is content">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use same technique as you used for the ng-class:

```
<li ng-class="{true: 'my_class', false: ''}[content]"  title="{{{true: 'title true', false: 'title false'}[content]}}">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IdBxje8PUMPEK3MnenXt?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Use an expression like this `{{ condition && if_true || if_false }}`. Example:

```
<li ng-class="{ 'my_class': !!content }" title="{{ !!content && content || otherContent }}">
```

Comment: Why `&&` and `||`? `? .. : ..` is simpler, isn't it?